# Style features UITableView aren't showing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I develop an app in Swift. On the storyboard I have added a view with a UITableView. I have set some the color, the height in the right menu as you can see right below :

[image]

But when I Launch the app, I get :

[image]

I didn't find why the settings are not showing. Do you have a clue ?

Comment: hi what do you expecting just remove gap between label textfield and headerview or what ?

Comment: Hi, 
I expect have a line between rows and the header color (like the storyboard #1)

Comment: have check cell.separatorInset may be problem in that.

Comment: Thx I will check this, but the problem with header(not showing) is the same problem that you said ?

Comment: like this   way you try and gives color check it      
 cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, cell.bounds.size.width, 0, 1)

Comment: listen if you getting issue of header view then set this code like :-

self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

Comment: [projectTable setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];

Answer (score 0):

> I expect have a line between rows and the header color

Try setting the scale of the simulator to 100%. `Window > Scale > 100%`. I'm not sure if that is your exact problem but I've noticed lines missing between cells when its not set to 100%. You can try running it on an actual device as well. Things don't display correctly on the simulator if its not viewed at 100%.

There are several weird issues with the simulator you should be aware of, here's a post listing a few other scenarios: [Simulator Gotchas](http://koreyhinton.com/blog/simulator-gotchas.html).

> the problem with header(not showing)

If you are also expecting a header you also need to make sure to provide a title for it:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "My header title"
}
```

For the above code to work you need to make sure you set your view controller to be the datasource in the storyboard by ctrl-dragging between table view and your view controller and setting the view controller as datasource:

[image: datasource]